# Metric focused on data updating

Tags: gooddata

How can I create a metric that would show me the date and time of the last time the data was updated within GoodData? Is it even possible?
I'm trying to create such a metric that displays it inside a dashboard in the following format: "This data has been updated XX/XX/XXX at 00:00".

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a new disconnected dataset to your logical model. The dataset should have a couple of columns:

- timestamp (attribute)
- fact (timestamp in integer)
- primary key, also known as Connection Point ( you can create on your own or use automatically generated by GoodData - records of ...)

Also, you can create a variable (type filtered value) using the timestamp attribute and add it to the dashboard using variable status.
Once such dataset is uploaded, create a simple report including the timestamp attribute and add it to your dashboard.